# Vertex styles not being displayed in loop diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I have the following source for a tikz-feynman diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex [dot] (o1);
    \vertex [right=of o1,dot] (i1);
    \vertex [above right=of i1] (it);
    \vertex [above=of it,crossed dot] (ot);
    \vertex [below right=of it,dot] (i2);
    \vertex [below left=of i2] (ib);
    \vertex [below=of ib] (ob);
    \vertex [right=of i2,dot] (o2);

    \diagram* {
      (o1) -- [gluon] (i1),
      (i2) -- [gluon] (o2),
      (o1) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ot),
      (ot) -- [fermion, quarter left] (o2),
      (o2) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ob),
      (ob) -- [fermion, quarter left] (o1),
      (i1) -- [fermion, quarter left] (it),
      (it) -- [fermion, quarter left] (i2),
      (i2) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ib),
      (ib) -- [fermion, quarter left] (i1),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:
[image: Basic example of "closing the loop"]

It is not clear to me why the vertex styles `dot` and `crossed dot` are not being displayed.

In general I would be happy with any style that suitably conveys that the loops are cut propagators, although this goes beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Poor form on my part, have updated!

Comment: This is really strange. Perhaps it has to do with the `\pgfextra` in `\def\tikzfeynman@commands@vertex{
  \path \pgfextra{\tikzfeynmanallowemptynodetrue}
        \pgfextra{\tikzfeynmanvertextrue}
        node}` in `/tikzlibraryfeynman.code.tex`. One option would be to just draw the vertices with a `\foreach` loop by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I really do not know what is going on here. All I can offer is a workaround that is based on a syntax that *should be* equivalent to what you are doing, but apparently is not.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}[every dot={/tikz/draw=black}]
    \path (0,0) node[vertex,dot] (o1) 
     node[vertex,right=of o1,dot] (i1)
    node[vertex,above right=of i1] (it)
    node[vertex,above=of it,crossed dot] (ot)
    node[vertex,below right=of it,dot] (i2)
    node[vertex,below left=of i2] (ib)
    node[vertex,below=of ib] (ob)
    node[vertex,right=of i2,dot] (o2);

    \diagram {
      (o1) -- [gluon] (i1),
      (i2) -- [gluon] (o2),
      (o1) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ot),
      (ot) -- [fermion, quarter left] (o2),
      (o2) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ob),
      (ob) -- [fermion, quarter left] (o1),
      (i1) -- [fermion, quarter left] (it),
      (it) -- [fermion, quarter left] (i2),
      (i2) -- [fermion, quarter left] (ib),
      (ib) -- [fermion, quarter left] (i1),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One possible, though unlikely, explanation is that this is triggered by the `\pgfextra` in `\def\tikzfeynman@commands@vertex{ \path \pgfextra{\tikzfeynmanallowemptynodetrue} \pgfextra{\tikzfeynmanvertextrue} node}` in `/tikzlibraryfeynman.code.tex`. The pgfmanual says on p. 162 that

> This effect can be achieved using the following path operation
>   \pgfextra. Note that this operation should only be used by real
>   experts and should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on
>   normal paths.

Quite possible that this is not the reason, but anyway I would like to argue that one should try to avoid `pfgextra`. It is not needed here either. One could simply define a pgfkey `vertextrue/.code={\tikzfeynmanallowemptynodetrue\tikzfeynmanvertextrue}` and then do `\path [vertextrue] node`.

Comment: Thanks! I would not know more than you as to whether your suggestion is the reason for the difference between our outputs however it is always interesting to know a little more about what goes on under the hood so it is appreciated.

Comment: @Charmander35 Thanks! I did a little more testing and it seems that this is not the reason, at least when I replace `\pgfextra` by the safer (?) syntax the issue is still there. `tikz-feynman` is overall a great package but there are a few things that could be improved. (I am still curious what an `anti Majorana` fermion is supposed to be. ;-)